# how to print the minimal rectangular in python?

Tags: python

this is the first time I am here to ask question,so I hope I am asking question correctly

I am asking for how to print the minimal rectangular in python
example1:

```
arr = [['x','x','o'],['x','x','o']]
```

in shape it will be:

```
xxo
xxo
```

I want it become

```
o
o
```

so it return

```
[['o'],['o']]
```

example2:

```
arr = [['x','x','o']]
```

in shape it will be:

```
xxo
```

I want it become:

```
o
```

so it return

```
[['o']]
```

example3:

```
arr = [['o'],['x'],['x']]
```

so it return:

```
[['o']]
```

example4:

```
arr = [['x'],['x']]
```

i want it to return:

```
[[]] or []
```

however,
`arr = [['x','o'],[''o','x']]`

will remain the same
which is `[['x','o'],[''o','x']]`

I hope that I explain it clearly.

I haven't got any idea yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating through the array, finding the minimum bounding box around the ‘o’ characters, and then extracting the corresponding subarray:

```
def minimal_rectangle(arr):
    min_row = len(arr)
    max_row = 0
    min_col = len(arr[0])
    max_col = 0

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            if arr[i][j] == 'o':
                min_row = min(min_row, i)
                max_row = max(max_row, i)
                min_col = min(min_col, j)
                max_col = max(max_col, j)

    if min_row == len(arr) or min_col == len(arr[0]):
        return []

    return [row[min_col:max_col+1] for row in arr[min_row:max_row+1]]

# Example usage:
arr1 = [['x', 'x', 'o'],
        ['x', 'x', 'o']]
print(minimal_rectangle(arr1))  

arr2 = [['x', 'x', 'o']]
print(minimal_rectangle(arr2))  
arr3 = [['o'], ['x'], ['x']]
print(minimal_rectangle(arr3))  

arr4 = [['x'], ['x']]
print(minimal_rectangle(arr4))  

arr5 = [['x', 'o'], ['o', 'x']]
print(minimal_rectangle(arr5))
```

Output:
[image]